# Creating dynamic components in loop causes flickering

Tags: angular

I've a loop of items which is updated every few seconds. Based on the type of the item, a different component is loaded. This update causes an empty template for a few seconds of each item.

Listing HTML:

```
<div ngFor="let ledgerDeposit of deposits">
    <ng-template #depositTarget></ng-template>
</div>
```

Listing component:

```
 @ViewChildren('depositTarget', { read: ViewContainerRef }) depositTargets: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>; 

    async ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.depositTargets.changes.subscribe(() => {
            this.loadComponents();
        });

        await this.loadDeposits(false);
    }

   async loadDeposits(forceRefresh: boolean) {
    this.deposits = await this.exchanges.getDeposits();
   }

    private loadComponents() {
        this.depositTargets.toArray().forEach((viewContainerRef, i) => {
            let deposit = this.deposits[i];
            let exchange = this.exchanges.getExchange(deposit.exchange);

            let componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(exchange.depositSingleComponentName);
            let componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
            componentRef.instance.deposit = this.deposits[i];
        });
    }
```

Is there a way to prevent flickering? Like caching components, so a component isn't recreated on each update?

Flickering demo:

[image: Flickering demo]

Comment: It's just some thought from me. Maybe you can use length and move() of ViewContainerRef to implement what you need. From the doc of createComponent, 'If index is not specified, the new View will be inserted as the last View in the container.'. Hence, container does maintain all the views created. You can navigate among them by referring to their indexes, I believe. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a `trackBy` so it doesn't recreate all the items in the list.

```
<div class="fund" *ngFor="let ledgerDeposit of deposits; trackBy: trackById">
    <ng-template #depositTarget></ng-template>
</div>
```